# How to execute a Julia script step by step?

Tags: julia

Is there any way in Julia to execute an existing script step by step in REPL meanwhile being able to modify/plot arrays? (As in the case of Matlab debugging)

Note: I am especially asking this for version 0.4 for which hopefully a new debugging system is being implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options:

- The [Debug package](https://github.com/toivoh/Debug.jl) provides step-by-step debugging. It hasn't yet been updated for 0.4, however.
- [Juno](https://github.com/one-more-minute/Juno-LT) provides some nice functionality for executing specific lines, and includes integrated plotting
- Copy/paste the script into the REPL

Indeed there is a more general debugger in the works, but it's not possible to say when it will be ready.

Comment: Is the work on the future debugger hosted in github?

Comment: For those interested, GUI-based debugging now works via the latest version of [Juno](http://junolab.org/). For now, start the debug mode using the `Juno.@step` macro, as GUI-based breakpoints are still being fine-tuned.